# XMLDocument body is undefined in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, firefox, dom

I read the MDN docs for [DOMImplementation.createDocument()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createDocument) and used the example listed there to create a new XHTML document.

The new document instance will have a `body` property in Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
var newDoc = document.implementation.createDocument ('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
var newBody = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'body');

newDoc.documentElement.appendChild(newBody);
console.log(newDoc.body) // false in Chrome - true in Firefox
```

The prototype of the `newDoc` is `XMLDocument` in both FF and Chrome, therefore I understand that it is expected not to have a `body` property.

However, because the result isn't consistent I figured out I could ask :)

Here is a CodePen with my code: http://codepen.io/janvidar/pen/RKRrRr

Comment: `false in Chrome - true in Firefox` - other way around, isn't it?

Comment: No no, it is present in Chrome 55 and `undefined` in Firefox 50.10

Comment: I guess I figured by "false in Chrome" meant it's undefined, and "true in firefox" meant it outputs the body ... boolean logic and all that

Comment: oh my God, you are right. It was the other way around. In my defense, I just got down from a very long flight haha. Thank you very much!

Comment: I figured that from the codepen - just wanted to be sure

Comment: I would try to work with childNodes or children of the newDoc created, as far as I see there where changes on the access to DOM properties in chrome, and probably differs a bit on firefox:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/DOM-attributes-now-on-the-prototype-chain

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript-DOM_Prototypes_in_Mozilla